# Can I compile remotely with Putty and sublime?

Tags: c++, ssh, g++, putty

Is there any way to compile programs remotely on Linux with Putty and Sublime? I'm running windows and my c++ compiler is different but my programs are graded on how they run when compiled on the server.

Answer (score 1):

I use winscp to copy files to a unix box to compile / run if I am editing on windows. or you could use pscp (part of putty but not graphical)

https://winscp.net/eng/download.php

Answer (score 0):

This may be a long way of doing it, but this is always what I have done when faced with this problem. (This is assuming that your code is saved on your windows machine and you want to compile it on your linux machine)

In the shell, use the touch command to create a new file

```
$ touch newFile.cpp
```

Then use nano to open the file and copy and paste your code into the shell.

```
$ nano newFile.cpp
```

then just use the command to compile and then execute.
There's probably a faster way to do but it works.